# Late 2013 MacBook iCloud Lock?

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, catalina

Just recently sold a Late 2013 MacBook Pro (upgraded to 16" MBP). I didn't manually remove Find My or sign out of iCloud on the device. However, I erased Macintosh HD and Macintosh HD - Data and reinstalled macOS Catalina. Will the new owner be locked out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably. I'm unable to upgrade to a more recent MacOS version on the same model. I inherited it from my brother and do not know his AppleID pwd. Apple support says there's no way forward, and that I need to keep using it with Mavericks.